# why my mesh deform when I delete shape key?

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

I just tried to delete shape keys and my mesh goes from this[image]

to this

[image]

Why is it doing this, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: I just solved it. i deleted all modifiers and physics and it works.thanks

Comment: Please provide this as an answer to help others who has the same problem :)

Comment: How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it by deleting all object modifiers and physics and it works.